# Универсальный шаблонизатор для файлов на js/ts

Tags: javascript, typescript, кодогенераторы

Стало напрягать создавать ручками много файлов и хотелось бы немного автоматизировать процесс.
Каким инструментом можно создавать файлы и директории по шаблону?

Как я это вижу: Я подготавливаю директорию с шаблоном, и при запуске у меня генерируются файлы.

Хочется, чтобы я мог в шаблонах оставлять переменные и заменять их на другие шаблоны или текст.

Если вы знаете типы файлов созданные для описания шаблонов, пишите, будет полезна любая информация.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такой препроцессор, называется [Pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html), на русском [здесь](https://gist.github.com/neretin-trike/53aff5afb76153f050c958b82abd9228). Его можно подключить с помощью [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/), пример можно посмотреть [здесь](https://github.com/yukal/template-presenta/blob/dev/gulpfile.js). И в добавок можно подключить вот этот мини инструмент [gulp-json-loader](https://github.com/yukal/gulp-json-loader), который позволяет автоматически подгружать данные из `JSON` файлов в зависимости от вашей структуры каталогов, у этой тулзы под капотом [gulp-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-data).